# Update a cell value from a DropDownList in another cell in same row

Tags: c#, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm struggling with a use-case scenario:

User selects a terminal and the services dropdown gets populated (cascading). The JSON that populates the services dropdown contains a field `Fee` that I want to pick and use it's value for the `ServiceFee` of the grid/datasource column for a row currently being edited/inserted

.[image: process]

I have tried two approaches so far:

**Approach #1:**
I tried to hook into the Service DropDownList's event to see what item user selctes and extract the `Fee` and them try to update the grid's edit/new row's dataItem's `ServiceFee` field. However, the place where I hooked in to the Service DropDownList's event had no access to the grid.

```
var gridMain = $("#serviceDetailsGrid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: kendoDataSource,
    pageable: false,
    sortable: false,
    toolbar: ["create"],
    columns:
    [
        { field: "ParkingServiceId", title: "Id", hidden: true },
        { field: "TerminalId", title: "Terminal", width: 130, template: getTerminalTitle, editor: terminalDropDownEditor },
        { field: "ServiceId", title: "Service", template: getServiceTitle, editor: serviceDropDownEditor },
        { field: "ParkingCardNumber", width: 120, title: "Card #" },
        { field: "ParkingCardIssueDate", width: 120, title: "Issued On", format: "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", template: "#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(ParkingCardIssueDate,  'dd-MMM-yyyy'), 'dd-MMM-yyyy') #" },
        { field: "ParkingCardExpiryDate", width: 120, title: "Expiry", format: "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", template:   "#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(ParkingCardExpiryDate, 'dd-MMM-yyyy'), 'dd-MMM-yyyy') #" },
        { field: "ServiceFee", width: 100, title: "Fee" },
        { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "Actions", width: "200px" }
    ],
    editable: "inline",
    cancel: function (e) { $('#serviceDetailsGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.cancelChanges(); },
}).data("kendoGrid");

function serviceDropDownEditor(container, options) {
    $('<input id="servicesDropDownList" required data-text-field="NameEnglish" data-value-field="Code" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
    .appendTo(container)
    .kendoDropDownList({
        optionLabel: "Select service...",
        autobind: false,
        dataTextField: "NameEnglish",
        dataValueField: "Code",
        change: serviceDropDown_OnChange
    });
}

function serviceDropDown_OnChange(a) {
    var serviceDropDown = $("input[id^='servicesDropDownList']").data("kendoDropDownList");
    var extract = serviceDropDown.dataItem(serviceDropDown.select());
    // I have the fee at extract.Fee but don't know how to send it back to grid
}
```

**Approach 2:**
I tried to hook into grid's `edit` event. But that even triggers only once and immediately upon new row or edit row. The Service DropDownList is cascaded. So user needs to select terminal first and then Service. The `edit` has already triggered before user makes these selections:

```
var gridMain = $("#serviceDetailsGrid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: kendoDataSource,
    pageable: false,
    sortable: false,
    toolbar: ["create"],
    columns:
    [
        { field: "ParkingServiceId", title: "Id", hidden: true },
        { field: "TerminalId", title: "Terminal", width: 130, template: getTerminalTitle, editor: terminalDropDownEditor },
        { field: "ServiceId", title: "Service", template: getServiceTitle, editor: serviceDropDownEditor },
        { field: "ParkingCardNumber", width: 120, title: "Card #" },
        { field: "ParkingCardIssueDate", width: 120, title: "Issued On", format: "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", template: "#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(ParkingCardIssueDate,  'dd-MMM-yyyy'), 'dd-MMM-yyyy') #" },
        { field: "ParkingCardExpiryDate", width: 120, title: "Expiry", format: "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", template:   "#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(ParkingCardExpiryDate, 'dd-MMM-yyyy'), 'dd-MMM-yyyy') #" },
        { field: "ServiceFee", width: 100, title: "Fee" },
        { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "Actions", width: "200px" }
    ],
    editable: "inline",
    cancel: function (e) { $('#serviceDetailsGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.cancelChanges(); },
    edit: function (e) {
        var model = e.model; //reference to the model that is about the be edited
        var container = e.container; //reference to the editor container

        //find second dropdown and then get the widget instance
        var serviceDropDownList = container.find("[data-role=dropdownlist]").eq(1).data("kendoDropDownList");

        // if DropDownListwidget is found
        if (serviceDropDownList) {
            var extract = serviceDropDownList.dataItem(serviceDropDownList.select());
            // I have "Select service" item here as the edit event triggered far too early

            console.log("Grid Edit Event --> DropDownList (Id: " + serviceDropDownList.id + "), Selected: " + extract, serviceDropDownList);
            e.model.ServiceFee = extract.Fee;
        }
    }
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

Here is debug view from IE for approach 2:

[image: debug process]

Now I'm thinking that I should hook into the Update/Confirm button and manually do the needful there but I need some input regarding Approaches 1 & 2 before I start Approach 3. Am I missing something here? Approach 1 was the best candidate AFAIK.

**Update**
Approach #1 got an update from Telerik forums here: http://www.telerik.com/forums/update-a-read-only-column-with-value-while-editing#dExxMF1g9UenKYD0vE_XkA

After testing the new Select event on the Serice DropDownList, I see a strange behaviour: It doesn't reflect the latest selected record but instead the last one. I replied to the official thread here:http://www.telerik.com/forums/update-a-read-only-column-with-value-while-editing#RXPhUgu-_0yo7MhPsaDTEw

Regards.

Comment: If you are using asp.net mvc, why is your grid not created using Razor? Also, what you wanna do doesn't have to happen on the client side. Just update the fee in your update action, and when you read the datasource after update the fee will be displayed.

Comment: It was originally MVC Helper based. But this grid is going to CRUD on a very basic data that I didn't wanted to AJAXify over to server such a simple list of certain object. So I had to attach to a local array and decided to go completely jQ as it was easy to have more control over the grid.